# Swapping Children between Two Expandable ListViews in Android

Tags: java, android, android-listview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have two expandable listviews in my android app. I populate the first expandable listview with a group which has six children. What i want is that when i click on a child it should get populated in second expandable listview along with its group name and that child should be removed from the first expandable listview. So when i click on the last remaining child of first expandable listview group it would also get populated in second expandable listview and as first expandable listview would have no child remaining in a group so it should remove the group as well. How to achieve this phenomenon????

Comment: All you need to do is to move your data object from one adapter into another and call notifyDataSetChanged() on both adapters.
I am not posting this as an answer because I haven't tried it on expandable list views, however this is the way you update your list views in general. Give it a try.